# How to show/display the second ListView after selecting a row in the first ListView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I am a new ASP.NET developer and I have to create a quiz engine application. I am using three LiveView controls to show:

***quiz information***, ***question information (based on the selected quiz on the first ListView)***, and ***answers information (based on the selected question on the second ListView)***

I have the following database design:

```
QuizContent Table: ID, QuizID, QuestionID, AnswerID, isCorrect
Quiz Table: QuizID, Title, Description, isSent
Question Table: QuestionID, Question, QuestionOrder, AnswerExplanation
Answers Table: AnswerID, Answer
```

**What I want now is the following:** when the user (who is the Admin) comes to the Quiz Engine Page, he should only see the first ListView which is mainly about the Quiz Information. And when he selects one of the quizzes, the second ListView will be displayed with the Question information of that selected quiz and so on for the third ListView. I am only facing problem in showing the second ListView. I don't know how to show it.

**So how to do that?**

I know I should not post too much code or information, but I have to do it to make it clear:

```
<div align="center">
            <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="QuizID" 
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" InsertItemPosition="LastItem" >

                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <tr style="">
                        <td>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="UpdateButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/update24.png" ToolTip="Update"  runat="server" CommandName="Update" />

                            <asp:ImageButton ID="CancelButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/cancel324.png" ToolTip="Cancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TitleTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Title") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="DescriptionTextBox" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>' />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <table id="Table1" runat="server" style="">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                No data was returned.</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </EmptyDataTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <tr style="">
                        <td>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="InsertButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/add24.png" ToolTip="Add"  runat="server" CommandName="Insert" />

                            <asp:ImageButton ID="CancelButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/clear24.png" ToolTip="Cancel"  runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" />
                        </td>

                        <%--<td>
                            &nbsp;</td>--%>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TitleTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Title") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="DescriptionTextBox" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>' />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr style="">
                        <td>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="DeleteButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/delete24.png" ToolTip="Delete"  runat="server" CommandName="Delete" />

                            <asp:ImageButton ID="EditButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/edit24.png" ToolTip="Edit"  runat="server" CommandName="Edit" />

                            <asp:ImageButton ID="SelectButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/select.png" ToolTip="Select"  runat="server" CommandName="Select" />
                            <%--<asp:Button ID="SelectButton" runat="server" CommandName="Select" Text="Select" />--%>
                        </td>
                        <%--<td>
                            <asp:Label ID="QuizIDLabel" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Eval("QuizID") %>' />
                        </td>--%>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="TitleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <div ><table id="thetable" width="97%" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px; border:2px solid #003366; font-size:13px; font-weight:bold;">
                        <thead>
                            <tr style="background-color:#C6D7B5;">
                                <th style="border-bottom:2px solid #003366; ">...</th>
                                <th style="border-bottom:2px solid #003366; ">Title</th>
                                <th style="border-bottom:2px solid #003366; ">Description</th>
                            </tr>
                       </thead>
                       <tbody><tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></tr></tbody>
                    </table></div>
                </LayoutTemplate>
                <SelectedItemTemplate>
                    <tr style="">
                        <td>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="DeleteButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/delete24.png" ToolTip="Delete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" />

                            <asp:ImageButton ID="EditButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/edit24.png" ToolTip="Edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" />
                        </td>
                        <%--<td>
                            <asp:Label ID="QuizIDLabel" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Eval("QuizID") %>' />
                        </td>--%>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="TitleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </SelectedItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:QuizSysDBConnectionString %>" 

                SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Quiz]" 
                DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Quiz] WHERE [QuizID] = @QuizID" 
                InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Quiz] ([Title], [Description]) VALUES (@Title, @Description)" 


                UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Quiz] SET [Title] = @Title, [Description] = @Description WHERE [QuizID] = @QuizID">
                <DeleteParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="QuizID" Type="Int32" />
                </DeleteParameters>
                <InsertParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Title" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Description" Type="String" />
                </InsertParameters>
                <UpdateParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Title" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Description" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="QuizID" Type="Int32" />
                </UpdateParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>

    <br /><br />

    <%--Second ListView that will contain the content of the quiz--%>
    <div align="center">
        <asp:ListView ID="ListView2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" 
            DataKeyNames="QuestionID" InsertItemPosition="LastItem" visible="false">

            <EditItemTemplate>

                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="UpdateButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/update24.png" ToolTip="Update" runat="server" CommandName="Update" />

                        <asp:ImageButton ID="CancelButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/cancel324.png" ToolTip="Cancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" />
                    </td>
                    <%--<td>
                        <asp:Label ID="QuestionIDLabel1" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("QuestionID") %>' />
                    </td>--%>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="QuestionTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("Question") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="QuestionOrderTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("QuestionOrder") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="AnswerExplanationTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("AnswerExplanation") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </EditItemTemplate>

            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <table runat="server" 
                    style="">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            No data was returned.</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>

            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="InsertButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/add24.png" ToolTip="Add" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" />

                        <asp:ImageButton ID="CancelButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/clear24.png" ToolTip="Cancel"  runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" />
                    </td>
                    <%--<td>
                        &nbsp;</td>--%>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="QuestionTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("Question") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="QuestionOrderTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("QuestionOrder") %>'/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="AnswerExplanationTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("AnswerExplanation") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </InsertItemTemplate>

            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="DeleteButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/delete24.png" ToolTip="delete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" />

                        <asp:ImageButton ID="EditButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/edit24.png" ToolTip="Edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" />

                        <asp:ImageButton ID="SelectButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/select.png" ToolTip="Select" runat="server" CommandName="Select" />
                            <%--<asp:Button ID="SelectButton" runat="server" CommandName="Select" Text="Select" />--%>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="QuestionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Question") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="QuestionOrderLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("QuestionOrder") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="AnswerExplanationLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("AnswerExplanation") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>

            <LayoutTemplate>
                <div ><table id="thetable" width="97%" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px; border:2px solid #003366; font-size:13px; font-weight:bold;">
                        <thead>
                            <tr style="background-color:#C6D7B5;">
                                <th style="border-bottom:2px solid #003366; ">...</th>
                                <th style="border-bottom:2px solid #003366; ">Question</th>
                                <th style="border-bottom:2px solid #003366; ">Question Order</th>
                                <th style="border-bottom:2px solid #003366; ">Answer Explanation</th>
                            </tr>
                       </thead>
                       <tbody><tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></tr></tbody>
                    </table></div>     
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <SelectedItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="DeleteButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/delete24.png" ToolTip="Delete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" />

                        <asp:ImageButton ID="EditButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/edit24.png" ToolTip="Edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="QuestionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Question") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="QuestionOrderLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("QuestionOrder") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="AnswerExplanationLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("AnswerExplanation") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </SelectedItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
        </div>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:QuizSysDBConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [Question].* FROM [Question] INNER JOIN [QuizContent] ON [QuizContent].[QuizID] = @QuizID"

            DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Question] WHERE [QuestionID] = @QuestionID" 
            InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Question] ([Question], [QuestionOrder], [AnswerExplanation]) VALUES (@Question, @QuestionOrder, @AnswerExplanation)" 


            UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Question] SET [Question] = @Question, [QuestionOrder] = @QuestionOrder, [AnswerExplanation] = @AnswerExplanation WHERE [QuestionID] = @QuestionID">

                <DeleteParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="QuestionID" Type="Int32" />
                </DeleteParameters>
                <InsertParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Question" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="QuestionOrder" Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="AnswerExplanation" Type="String" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ListView1" Name="QuizID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
                </InsertParameters>
                <UpdateParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Question" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="QuestionOrder" Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="AnswerExplanation" Type="String" />
                </UpdateParameters>

            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ListView1" Name="QuizID" 
                    PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

        <br /><br />

    <%--Third ListView that will contain the content of the quiz--%>
    <div align="center">
        <asp:ListView ID="ListView3" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" 
            DataKeyNames="AnswerID" InsertItemPosition="LastItem">

            <EditItemTemplate>

                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="UpdateButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/update24.png" ToolTip="Update" runat="server" CommandName="Update" />

                        <asp:ImageButton ID="CancelButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/cancel324.png" ToolTip="Cancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" />
                    </td>
                    <%--<td>
                        <asp:Label ID="AnswerIDLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AnswerID") %>' />
                    </td>--%>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="AnswerTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("Answer") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </EditItemTemplate>

            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <table runat="server" 
                    style="">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            No data was returned.</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>

            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="InsertButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/add24.png" ToolTip="Add" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" />

                        <asp:ImageButton ID="CancelButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/clear24.png" ToolTip="Cancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" />
                    </td>
                    <%--<td>
                        &nbsp;</td>--%>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="AnswerTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("Answer") %>'/>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </InsertItemTemplate>

            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="DeleteButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/delete24.png" ToolTip="Delete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" />

                        <asp:ImageButton ID="EditButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/edit24.png" ToolTip="Edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" />
                    </td>
                    <%--<td>
                        <asp:Label ID="AnswerIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AnswerID") %>' />
                    </td>--%>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="AnswerLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Answer") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>

            <LayoutTemplate>
                <div ><table id="thetable" width="97%" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px; border:2px solid #003366; font-size:13px; font-weight:bold;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr style="background-color:#C6D7B5;">
                            <th style="border-bottom:2px solid #003366; ">...</th>
                            <th style="border-bottom:2px solid #003366; ">Answer</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody><tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></tr></tbody>
                </table></div>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <SelectedItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="DeleteButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/delete24.png" ToolTip="Delete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" />

                        <asp:ImageButton ID="EditButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/edit24.png" ToolTip="Edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="AnswerLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("Answer") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </SelectedItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
        </div>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:QuizSysDBConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [Answers].* FROM [Answers] INNER JOIN [QuizContent] ON [QuizContent].QuestionID = @QuestionID"

            DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Answers] WHERE [AnswerID] = @AnswerID" 
            InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Answers] ([Answer]) VALUES (@Answer)" 


            UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Answers] SET [Answer] = @Answer WHERE [AnswerID] = @AnswerID">
                <DeleteParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="AnswerID" Type="Int32" />
                </DeleteParameters>
                <InsertParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Answer" Type="String" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ListView2" Name="QuestionID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
                </InsertParameters>
                <UpdateParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Answer" Type="String" />
                </UpdateParameters>

            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ListView2" Name="QuestionID" 
                    PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**NOTE:**
I don't have any code-behind. And again the problem is as following: when I run the code, I will see the three ListView controls. It should show only one of them. And when the user selects one of the rows, the second ListView will be displayed and so on for the third ListView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I had already helped you with a similar question, this time, I decided to see exactly the problem so I created tables locally with your structure and I could replicate your problem

Basically your queries were wrong and I do not know how you were expecting to hide/show the `ListView` controls without writing code behind nor JavaScript...

I must say that I agree with @GrayFox374 you should show more initiative...

Well anyhow...

I already tested this code and I think it's exactly what you are looking for:

Basically when the page loads only the quizes table is visible, when a quiz is selected, if it has records, the questions table is shown and finally when you select a question, the answers table is shown only if it contains data.

### Output

#### When page is loaded

[image]

#### When a quiz is selected

[image]

#### When a question is selected

[image]

### Code behind

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            this.InitializeListView(this.ListView2);
            this.InitializeListView(this.ListView3);
        }
    }

    protected void ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.InitializeListView(this.ListView2);
        this.InitializeListView(this.ListView3);
    }

    protected void ListView2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.InitializeListView(this.ListView3);
    }

    private void InitializeListView(ListView listView)
    {
        listView.SelectedIndex = -1;
        listView.EditIndex = -1;
        listView.DataBind();

        listView.Visible = listView.Items.Count > 0;
    }
```

### ASPX

**Note: just showing the code I updated**

```
     <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="QuizID" 
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" InsertItemPosition="LastItem" 
                onselectedindexchanged="ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged" >
.....

 <asp:ListView ID="ListView2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" 
            DataKeyNames="QuestionID" InsertItemPosition="LastItem"
            onselectedindexchanged="ListView2_SelectedIndexChanged">
....
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:QuizSysDBConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT        QuestionID, Question, QuestionOrder, AnswerExplanation
FROM            Question
WHERE        (QuestionID IN
                             (SELECT DISTINCT QuestionID
                               FROM            QuizContent
                               WHERE        (QuizID = @QuizID)))"
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ListView1" Name="QuizID" DefaultValue="0" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
.....

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:QuizSysDBConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT        AnswerID, Answer
FROM            Answers
WHERE        (AnswerID IN
                             (SELECT DISTINCT AnswerID
                               FROM            QuizContent
                               WHERE        (QuestionID = @QuestionID)))"

            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ListView2" Name="QuestionID" DefaultValue="0"
                    PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
```

**Note, if this doesn't work I would strongly recommend you to run the queries manually against your database to discard data issues**

Well that's it I hope I didn't forget to add more modifications

Comment: Thanks very much for your continuous help. I really appreciate it. It works well with me now.

Comment: This works for existing records in the QuizContents, but if you are creating a new quiz from scratch, with new questions and new answers, you cannot toggle the 2nd listview, which is what he originally asked for.  For quizzes that already have questions and answers assigned through QuizContents, yes, this works.  But how do you get them there if this is the only interface?  That's why I keep harping on the overall design needing some tweaking.

Comment: @Jupaol, I am facing now a problem with inserting a new quiz. When I inserted it then selected it, the second ListView wasn't displayed. So How I can display it. I am struggling with it for two days without any luck. Could you please help me with it?

Answer (score 1):

I remember helping you on a related issue to this same project - [How to develop this ListView which depends on another ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516402/how-to-develop-this-listview-which-depends-on-another-listview) -which you never followed up on.  Looking at your history, you seem to be intent on having that Stack Overflow community do just about all of your work for you.  Nearly every question is about a different aspect of this same project.

rant->I would feel bad about this approach if I were you, because you
are not demonstrating the initiative, the drive to take ownership over
your craft.  You seem content to let others toil while you reap the
bounty, while your level of understanding is barely nudged from its
starting point.  But whatever... some of us just like to solve
problems and always strive to widen our skillset.  We just wish more
of our colleagues which as passionate and committed to the craft.
<- end rant

solution->
The same things I mentioned in your other post apply here.  To start with, you have questionable design.  Here, you want to bind ListView2 (Questions) to ListView1 (Quizzes), where there is nothing in the schema to join them!!!  You could do some esoteric, convoluted joins to link Questions to Quizzes through the QuizContents table's keys to both of the other tables, but in your presentation, QuizContents comes AFTER those two, so even that wouldn't work.  This flat out cannot be done in your current setup.  Look at what I recommended in the above mentioned link, and even if you disagree, if you take a little more time out to think about the design first before rushing to hack away and code as you go, you'll see that what you are attempting is not going to work.  Revamp your design.  solution->

Comment: Thanks for your lengthy feedback. First of all, let me explain to you why I came up with this design. I came up with it because I have different types of question such as multiple choice questions with single answer or with multiple answers, and True or False questions.

My design is good for this and it was recommended too by StackOverFlow community. I could be able to do insert, edit, delete in the all ListViews and I could be able to linked them. What I want now is to hide and show the second ListView based on the selection of any row in the first ListView.

Comment: It's true that you can do inserts edits and deletes in the listviews.  What your design does not take into account is this, you cannot directly link a question to a quiz, or and answer to a quiz.  They share nothing to join on.  Since this is the case, the entire premise of hiding or showing the 2nd listview (Questions) based on the selected row in the first listview can never be carried out with this design. If your Questions table had a QuizID, then yes, no problem, but that opens up new problems, for example, if you wanted to use the same ? in multiple quizzes you'd need multiple rows.

Comment: thanks for your explanation. What I want is to develop a quiz engine. Mainly, I have two kinds of questions; multiple choice with a single answer and multiple choice with a single answer. I designed the database in order to avoid any redundancy in Answers or Questions table. For example, I may have more than one question with True or False, so I think this design will fix this problem and so on. The above answer suggested by Jupaol works with me but I am facing a problem now with inserting a new quiz with new questions and answers. The second and third ListViews will not be shown.

Comment: That's exactly what I was saying.  If you applied the solution I proposed in the other post you made, where you select a quiz ID and then assign available questions and answers via ListBox controls, that will allow you to do EVERYTHING.

Comment: OK. Could you please provide me with an example about this?